Docking area on KDE Plasma overlaps with right aligned panel widgets
I have an issue with the layout of my KDE Plasma panel: sometimes (now and then) the docking area is pushed to the right end of the panel, ignoring the widgets placed there, so that both overlap:

Anyone got an idea why this happens? And how I can solve that issue?
